# how to group_concat two columns

Tags: mysql

I have one table with two columns parent_string and child string like this

```
id  parent_string             child_string
 1    0|4#festivals$Festiv     NULL
 2    0|4#festivals$Festiv     1|4@5#diwali$Deepavali
 3    0|4#festivals$Festiv     1|4@6#christmas$Christmas
 4    0|8#birthday$Birthday    1|8@9#for-mom$For Mom
 5    0|8#birthday$Birthday    1|8@10#for-dad$For Dad
```

If i want to select id in(1,2,3) then

I want output concat string like following:

```
0|4#festivals$Festiv~1|4@5#diwali$Deepavali~1|4@6#christmas$Christmas
```

how to do this?

Comment: Are you looking at a cartesian product of parent_string and child_string ?

like parent_string_1 | child_string_1 | childstring_2 | childstring_3...
parent_string_2 | child_string_1 | childstring_2 | childstring_3... ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `concat_ws` and `group concat` with custom `separator` on the fields ...

**Example**:

```
select
       concat_ws( '|', parent_string, group_concat( child_string separator '|' ) )
  from table_ame
 group by parent_string
```

**Refer to Documentation**:
[**CONCAT_WS(separator,str1,str2,...)**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws)

- CONCAT_WS() stands for Concatenate With Separator and is a special
  form of CONCAT(). The first argument is the separator for the rest of
  the arguments. The separator is added between the strings to be
  concatenated. The separator can be a string, as can the rest of the
  arguments. If the separator is NULL, the result is NULL

[**GROUP_CONCAT(expr)**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

- This function returns a string result with the concatenated non-NULL
  values from a group. It returns NULL if there are no non-NULL values